Creating a new file for a SQL database
I'm curious if I need to point to somewhere after creating a new file for a huge database (almost 15 TB).
ALl guides and tests I did personally, I only created a new file:
ALTER DATABASE MYDB ADD FILE TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]

I'm only wondering if in a huge database, I need to do anything else for the data to start flowing through the new file. WE unfortunately can't add more space on the disk since it's a EC2 instance.
The disk has already 2 files ( I don't know who created a .MDF and a .NDF in the same drive ) so I'm planning to add a new volume and add a new file to the database, hoping the new file will start to grow leaving these 2 in peace until I find a better solution.
